# Unable to get data of Present Month in Apache Superset

Tags: report, apache-superset

I am using `Apache Superset` for reporting purpose. I am want to draw a chart to show the graph for `present Month`. I used several ways but it is showing me the last day of the month. I used this method and other like `start of this month` It is showing me end of this month. Please show me the correct way to get the data of the current month.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

After a rigorous research I found the answer. here it is

```
datetrunc(datetime("this month start"), month)
```